# What's the difference between Active Directory and Computer Management?

Tags: active-directory, gpo

If you want to create a user or a group, you can do it using Active directory or Computer Management. So what's the difference between Active directory and Computer Management?

In an organization, what are the different ways to create users and groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer Management is a local applet on your system. If you create a user here (MyComputer01), that user can only login on that computer (MyComputer01).

Active Directory is a centralized management system for a network of computers (Computer02, Computer03, etc.). If a user is created in Active Directory, it can then login to other systems on the network, it's not bound to a single system.